# 18'x16' Pergola Questions

Tags: framing, pergola

So I’m looking at building a pergola on top of our raised deck off the back of our house. Total dimensions would be 18’x16′ (roughly), raised 8′ above our deck. Our deck is raised off the ground 4′-6′ due to the slope of the lot, so I was planning on running the posts through the deck to ground, mounted to blocks on concrete.

For layout, I was wanting to have two rows of three posts (6×6 pressure treated brown) with the posts 8’3″ c-c in each row. I was ‘hoping’ to have the two rows 13′ apart from each other. At the top of each row of 3 posts I would mount my 2×8 beams on either side of the post, overhanging by about 12″. I would mount knee braces on each post (one on outside posts angled in, and two on center posts) supporting the beams. Centered on top of the beams, I would mount 16′ rafters (thinking 16 oc), overhanging each end by about 18″. I’m debating 2″x2″ slats on top for additional shade.

I don’t have a drawing, but I have some images that are very similar to what I am planning (from Google). [This first one](https://www.ohiohardwoodfurniture.com/upload/images/products/berlin_gardens/pergolas/outback/15%C3%9723-outback-pergola-in-ce.jpg) shows the general shape and layout of what I’m planning (two rows of three posts).

[This second image](https://sunsetpergolas.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/pergola_kit_online.jpg) is pretty accurate as to how I am planning on mounting my beams to my posts, as well as the braces on each post (two on middle one in foreground and one on corner posts in background). One difference is I was planning on having knee braces along the back row of posts as well as my structure would NOT be fastened to my house in any way.

So, a couple questions I have are. Do I run risk of sagging with the 2x6x16′ rafters spanning beams 13′ apart? I tried using [this span calculator](https://www.awc.org/codes-standards/calculators-software/spancalc) to help but I was not entirely sure to input for all the parameters.
I think it may be using data for rafters that have a load of sheathing on it? Not entirely sure… If I run risk of sagging, could I just jump up to 2x8 rafters? Maybe make the beams 2x10 then to compensate?

Another question, the beams I am mounting to my posts, I cannot seem to find a 2x8x18′ length.. So I was hoping to split each beam into two, using four 2x8x10’s and butting them together on each side of the post supported with some type of hanger. Am I going to run into any issues with this? The second image I linked actually does exactly this as I was planning. I was hoping to bolt directly through beams and post with nut and washer on each side (two per beam so 4 on the middle post)

Another question. Do I need knee braces going both directions? I was planning on doing them running the direction of my three posts, but do I also need them running the other direction? If I do, do I need another set of beams running that direction as well for the knee braces to attach to or can I fix them to the rafters. (I could raise the post to match rafter height and attach the two outside rafters to the post rather than float on the beam if needed)
edit: I should mention that I am planning on bracing the posts to the deck structural frame as they go by. Probably just with a coupling 2x6s on angled to various deck beams (it's all hidden).

Final question.. Wood type? I'm having a real hard time finding timber in the lengths and sizes I need. For three of the posts i need 6x6x14 to reach ground, while the other three would be maybe 6x6x12. Same goes for the beams (2'x8'x18'ish) and rafters (2'x6'x16'). I would absolutely love to do this in cedar, but I cannot find anywhere I could get the posts that long. Not 100% sure about the beams and rafters either. Would I run into issues if I did the posts in pressure treated (few suppliers have a red PT wood) and the beams and rafters in cedar (if I can find board long enough)? I guess that also loops back to my second question, could I butt two of the beams together on the side of a post to make my 18'ish beam.

Comment: Do you have any snow load?  2x6 cedar  16  feet is not going to last., with roof on it.

Comment: May want taller post, at 8 feet beam may block  view and feel compact.. And walk into hanging plants.

Comment: This is a rather broad question. You might want to read up on [ask] and then see if you can pare this down some.

Comment: What does "  mounted to blocks on concrete. "  mean.

Comment: If you’re complaining about, “few suppliers have red PT wood”, then you’re really going to complain when you find a sawmill that will custom cut Cedar (or Redwood) for you.

Comment: @RobertMoody We do receive snow yes. I didn't think I was accumulate much with 16" centers and only 13' spanning between beams. As for height, I'm limited under a powerline running at 108".

Comment: @AlaskaMan [Deck blocks](https://cdn.rona.ca/images/39935002_L.jpg). The post sits in a shoe which rests on the block. The block I will have sitting on concrete.

Comment: Due to the snow,,The smallest i feel ok about is 2x8.  And in cedar would be 2x10.

Comment: The one in the pics is  the way to do it.  Other than getting material that is going to be a task.